# How can I do GPU passthrough with VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, gpu, gaming

I've installed Ubuntu 17.04 with a VirtualBox VM that contains a fresh Windows 10 install. I want to try to use this VM for gaming.

My CPU is an Intel Core i7 7700HQ that seems to support every virtualization-related option Intel has to offer, as shown in [this page](https://www.intel.fr/content/www/fr/fr/products/processors/core/i7-processors/i7-7700hq.html).

How can I give total access to my NVidia GTX 1050 GPU to this virtual machine ?

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Your CPU supports VT-d and VT-x which is required to do this.  VirtualBox just doesn't support it.  Use Hyper-V or VMWare.